# How do I get the VideoListByID query data form user with Google App Script HTML Service

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, youtube-javascript-api

Hello I am working on a Google App script project which interacts with Youtube Data API 3

Right now I am using the  function videosListById 
i need to get the video list id from user by a HTML  form which i have already but data from the form is not connected to the script

Need help with the data input and  connection  with front end This is my code

I tried to get the data by id but inside the videoListByID but still no success

.Gs part
       /**getting Videos from Youtube with IDs**/

```
 function videosListById(data) {

var mid = data.mids;
var blogid = data.BLOGID;

  // Uncomment this for furure
 return mid + blogid;
 Logger.log(mid+blogid)
 // var mid = ('Ks-_Mh1QhMc')         /** video id **/
 var results = YouTube.Videos.list("id,snippet",{'id': mid});
  for(var i in results.items) {
  var item = results.items[i];
     Logger.log('%s Description: %s', item.snippet.title, 
       item.snippet.description);
```

HTML Part of code

```
           <html>
 <head>
 <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
 Please fill in the form below.<br><br>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run.withFailureHandler
(Logger.log(data)).withSuccessHandler
(console.log).videosListById(data);return false;">
  videoID:
  <input type="text" name="mids"><br><br>

  BlogID:
  <input type="text" name="BLOGID"><br><br>


  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
 </form><br>
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you add the information? 1. Can you provide the function for loading HTML? 2. Does the function of ``videosListById()`` work you want? If you can do, could you please update your question? I think that also those information will help users think of about your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by myself , the issues is when i search with keyword the extracted description is not fully extracted using this method we can pass the video id to next function and get the description

```
function searchByKeyword(){

var results = YouTube.Search.list("id,snippet", {q : "trailers", maxResults: 
"1",type: 
"video"});
Logger.log(' search results: %s', results.items);

for(var i in results.items) {
var item = results.items[i];
Logger.log("[%s] Title: %s", item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
}
var item = results.items[i];


var results = YouTube.Videos.list("id,snippet",{'id': item.id.videoId });
for(var i in results.items) {
var item = results.items[i];
Logger.log('%s Description: %s', item.snippet.title, item.snippet.description);


}

for(var i in results.item) {
 var item = results.item[i];

}
```